# Error while creating slice of bool type in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to create slice of type bool but receiving error "cannot make type bool"

```
isVisited := make(bool,5,5)
```

`./jdoodle.go:10:19: cannot make type bool`

I also checked slice doc https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

And several other articles on Golang but no success .

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `[]`. To make `isVisited` a slice you need to do `isVisited := make([]bool, 5, 5)`.

`[]bool` denotes a slice of type `bool`.

There's a nice example in Effective Go both in section about [make()](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make) and [slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).

Comment: My bad couldn't see minor detail.Thanks